# getItem(position) returns same object for different values of position

Tags: android, listview, cursor, adapter, listadapter

I have a adapter with the following piece of (test) code in *public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)*:

```
    Cursor itemCursor = (Cursor) getItem(position);
    Cursor itemCursor2 = (Cursor) getItem(position+1);

    String itemTitle = itemCursor.getString(itemCursor
            .getColumnIndex(ItemColumns.TITLE));
    String itemTitle2 = itemCursor2.getString(itemCursor2
            .getColumnIndex(ItemColumns.TITLE));
```

I override "DragSortCursorAdapter" so getItem() is overridden to look like this:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    int item = mListMapping.get(position, position);
    return super.getItem(item);
    //return super.getItem(position);
}
```

the getItem which is called from here is the normal implementation from "android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getItem"

The problem is that itemCursor and itemCursor2 always is the same object. With same object ID and everything - I have no idea how this is possible since getItem is called with different arguments, and the list I output to the screen only shows different values.

In other words, when my adapter iterates the list it seems to do like this:

**First list Item:**

```
Cursor itemCursor = (Cursor) getItem(0);
Cursor itemCursor2 = (Cursor) getItem(0+1);
```

itemCursor and itemCursor2 are both 413d4800

**Second list Item:**

```
Cursor itemCursor = (Cursor) getItem(1);
Cursor itemCursor2 = (Cursor) getItem(1+1);
```

itemCursor and itemCursor2 are now both 4155aef8

Shouldn't at least itemCursor2 from the first iteration and itemCursor2 from the second iteration be identical?

In any case - can someone please help me with what is going on here? They both have the type "android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@4155aef8" which may or may not be relevant - I'm not sure.

**EDIT** The overridden getItem() is working. mListMapping.get(position, position); returns the correct value and *item* is indeed two different numbers - returning the same object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The problem is that itemCursor and itemCursor2 always is the same object.

Correct.

> I have no idea how this is possible since getItem is called with different arguments

Lots of methods can return the same value given different arguments.

A `CursorAdapter` wraps a `Cursor`. `getItem()` will *always* return this `Cursor`. However, `getItem()` will position the internal index of the `Cursor` to be the specified position. Hence, while the `Cursor` itself is the same object, what the `Cursor` returns for methods like `getString()` will differ, because the internal position within the `Cursor` is different.

You can see this in action by examining `getItem()` in [the `CursorAdapter` source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java).

Comment: I understand. But the obvious next question is them. How can I reorder the cursors in my list. I do run notifydatasetchanged() but it takes half a second creating some strange flickering unless I can make sure Android draws the right objects in the right position at the moment the users puts it there.

Comment: @Markus: "How can I reorder the cursors in my list" -- there is only one `Cursor`. You cannot reorder a set of 1. If you wish to reorder the *contents* of the `Cursor`, you have to create a fresh `Cursor` and specify your desired sort order.

Comment: Okay - I'll rephrase my question then. Is it possible to fetch the *correct content in the cursor* without fetching the data from the data source (a database) again. The data is obviously there somewhere. In any case - thank you for your help